# Create a thumbnail from url

Tags: ios, avassetimagegenerator

I am using the code below to create a video thumbnail from a Url, the code is working perfect but it takes long time and it's jamming the app till it's create the image.

Her is my code:

```
NSString *one = self.currentList.videoLink;
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:one];
    AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:imageURL options:nil];


        AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
        generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
        NSError *err = NULL;
        CMTime time = CMTimeMake(2,1);
        CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
        UIImage *oneme = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
        [self.videoImage setImage:oneme];
        self.videoImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

As I said, the code work fine. Can any one help me to solve the delay in creating the thumbnail?

Thanks and I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If the `one` URL is some remote URL, you are networking synchronously. That would be a lot of your problem right there. You're blocking the main thread while you network ("jamming the app", as you put it). Network properly, with URLSession or AFNetworking or whatever. That way, you don't block the main thread.

(By the way, blocking the main thread will cause your app to crash if you do it on a device. You might not even get into the app store, if Apple notices you're doing that.)